# read json from web by scrapy in Python2

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract JSON data from a web page, so I've inspected it. Data I need is stored in the below format:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
     'data I want to extract'
    }
    </script>
```

I tried to use:

```
import scrapy
import json

class OpenriceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'openrice'
    allowed_domains = ['www.openrice.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
            'accept':     'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        }
        url = 'https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/r-kitchen-one-cafe-sha-tin-western-r483821'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):  # response = request url ?
        items = []
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response)
```

But it doesn't work, how should I change it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to locate that `script` element in the HTML source, extract it's text and only then load with `json.loads()`:

```
script = response.xpath("//script[@type='application/ld+json']/text()").extract_first()
json_data = json.loads(script)
print(json_data)
```

Here, I am using the not so common `application/ld+json` to locate the `script`, but there are many other options as well - like, locate the script using some text you know it is in the script itself:

```
//script[contains(., 'Restaurant')]
```